# How to change highlight colour of a portion of a text in rich text box?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, highlight

I am new to WPF's RichTextBox. I would like to know how to highlight text on a line with a specific colour.

Let's say I have a rich text box with a yellow background and assign to it a flow document.

```
richTextBox.Background = Brushes.LightYellow;
var mcFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();
var para = new Paragraph();
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the first line.\n"));
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the second line.\n"));
para.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is the third line."));
mcFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(para);
richTextBox.Document = mcFlowDoc;
```

**What would I have to do next to change the third line's highlight colour to red?** I am not talking about selection highlight colour, but normal text highligting (like in WordPad)

If there is a solution, I would like it in C# code, I want to stay away from XAML editing.

Comment: You have got the possible [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12437503/468718) by [Blam](http://stackoverflow.com/users/607314/blam) Also you can refer the msdn article on [Flow Document Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx), it has all the commonly possible usage on `FlowDocument`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Run run = new Run("Red is the third line.\n");
    // run.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    run.Background = Brushes.Red;
    para.Inlines.Add(run);
```

Comment: If I replace `Foreground` for `Background` it is what I want. Thank you!