# Editable text control with inlines?

Tags: c#, wpf

With `TextBlock` one can use inlines for formatted text, e.g. different background colors for each text section. But a `TextBlock` is not editable.

Does WPF offer an editable text control with inlines for formatted text?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970779(v=vs.110).aspx) Control:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
             <Run Background="Red"> I am red </Run>
             <Run Background="Green">And I am green</Run>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

If you want to change it programmatically you may want to take a look at this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435340/how-to-change-highlight-colour-of-a-portion-of-a-text-in-rich-text-box).

Or, as a better solution, you can just bind the background to your model data and use some custom [value to color converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982150/wpf-binding-set-listbox-item-text-color-based-on-property).

```
<Run Background="{Binding ColorDeterminingProp, Converter={StaticResource myConverterInstance}}"> I am red </Run>
```